# Migration Script in MS SQL Server: Need to migrate some data from one table into another table for Normalization purpose

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `Employee`:

```
EmpId    Add1    Add2      Add3
--------------------------------------
  1      GOA     MUMBAI    DELHI
  2      NULL    MUMBAI    NULL
  3      GOA     MUMBAI    NULL
  4      NULL    NULL      NULL
```

I need to get the values of `Add1`, `Add2`, `Add3` inserted into another table only if the respective column is not null.

The expected result should look like this:

```
EmpId    Address
----------------
  1      GOA    
  1      MUMBAI 
  1      DELHI  
  2      MUMBAI 
  3      GOA    
  3      MUMBAI
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to use a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT EmpId, Add1 AS Address
FROM Employee
WHERE Add1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpId, Add2
FROM Employee
WHERE Add2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpId, Add3
FROM Employee
WHERE Add3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY EmpId
```

Comment: `UNION` might be better than `UNION ALL`.  De-deplication after the fact would be a pain.

Comment: @BaconBits I don't see any information about wanting to remove duplicates.  I'll stick with `UNION ALL` unless the OP gives me feedback otherwise.

Comment: That's why I said, "might."  But look at the resulting table structure.  What's the only candidate key?  `(EmpId, Address)`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the response, its actually what I needed. Also I needed UNION in query. 
Thanks 'Bacon Bits'  for highlighting the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may use UNPIVOT statement in this case.

```
SELECT EmpId, Address
FROM Employee
UNPIVOT (Address FOR AddN IN (Add1, Add2, Add3)) AS UT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would also request you to suggest as what if have to remove the duplication and get only unique (Add1, Add2, Add3)

Comment: Answer from 'Tim Biegeleisen' have helped me to get expected result where I just replaced 'UNION ALL' with 'UNION' but would also be interested to see if UNIQUE record with your solution.

Comment: You must just add DISTINCT keyword after SELECT to get only unique records.

Comment: Yup this helped, Thanks